# React native Expo bottom navigation (controls)

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-development, react-native-native-module

Is there a way i can remove this black bottom controls on Android?
Can i control immersive mode or full Screen mode with only react-native or expo?
I want to either remove it or at least not see black color

[image: Pic info]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for would involve going into "full screen mode"?  If so, have you looked at [expo-full-screen](https://github.com/Luluno01/expo-full-screen) ?

Comment: I've tried: "androidNavigationBar": {
   "visible": "sticky-immersive"
  }
as well, but no luck, i get sticky immersive on the navigation bar, but now my status bar gets a black background.